# Excel VBA - Fetch Blog Post Text without Loading Images

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to fetch blog post (text only) using the below code:

```
Function extractPostBody(myURL As String) As String
Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
IE.Visible = True

IE.navigate myURL

On Error GoTo 0

Do
DoEvents
Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
Set Doc = IE.Document

For i = 0 To Doc.getElementsByTagName("p").Length - 1
    If InStr(1, Doc.getElementsByTagName("p")(i).innerText, "Tags: ") > 0 Then
        Exit For
    End If
    PostBody = PostBody & vbNewLine & Doc.getElementsByTagName("p")(i).innerText

Next i

IE.Quit
extractPostBody = PostBody

End Function
```

Once the text is retrieved, I assign it to a cell and then use the split function to count the number of words in the extracted text. The code works however, for websites that has a lot of images, the code waits until these pictures are loaded which drastically slows down execution.

Is there another way to get the text off a blog without waiting for the pictures to load?

EDIT:

Using Jeeped's suggestion, I am using the below code which I took from another StackOverflow post however can't seem to go back to it to give credit to the author:

```
Function ScrapeWebPage(ByVal URL As String)
    Dim HTMLDoc As New HTMLDocument
    Dim tmpDoc As New HTMLDocument
    Dim PostBody As String

    Dim i As Integer, row As Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Set XMLHttpRequest = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    XMLHttpRequest.Open "GET", URL, False
    XMLHttpRequest.send

    While XMLHttpRequest.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Wend

    With HTMLDoc.body
        'Set HTML Document
        .innerHTML = XMLHttpRequest.responseText

        Set ListItems = .getElementsByTagName("p")

        'Let's process each data of the list items
        For Each li In ListItems
            PostBody = PostBody & vbNewLine & li.innerText
        Next
    End With

    ScrapeWebPage = PostBody
End Function
```

This works however the code is now returning a captcha message which obviously I can't fill up anymore because I can't display IE. or can I?

Comment: Use a XMLHTTP or ServerXMLHTTP  object. You won't have to load an InternetExplorer.Application object and you can parse out the `.responseText` in pretty much the same way you are currently getting the information for the IE.document.

Comment: Share `myURL` for sample.

Comment: Thank you @Jeeped. I did try it using XMLHTTP however now I can't seem to get pass the captcha of the site.

Comment: Thank you @omegastripes for responding. here's a sample blog

Comment: oppps. here it is https://www.brandwatch.com/2014/08/brands-and-timing/

Comment: That might sound strange, XHR response I've received by the link is exactly the same as in my browser, but not a captcha. Try to get the content via [archive.org](https://archive.org/web/), eg you can make XHR to get [the page with all saves](http://web.archive.org/web/*/https://www.brandwatch.com/2014/08/brands-and-timing/), and find the latest saved link by parsing 2 paragraphs starting from string `<p class="wbUrl">` with regex.

Comment: Hi @omegastripes you lost me in the XHR response. would you be so kind to share your test code? I am not that familiar with VBA however I try to learn as much as I could. both codes I have above are all edits from other posts (which reminds me to make sure to remember where I got them so that I can give credit to the original author).